# How to apply the OpenGL function

Tags: function, opengl, window

I have a problem of applying some functions of OpenGL(e.g. glDeleteBuffers). 
My computer's spec is;

- Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series
- Operating system: Windows 7
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600

I used OpenGL Extensions Viewer 4.4.3 to view information about OpenGL.
I update the latest version of graphic card and found that version of OpenGL is 4.4 and it shows like below picture:

[image]

I am not sure what I can do more from now. I would like to use functions like glDeletBuffers, glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData...

Give me some help

Comment: We would need to see your code. In particular, we would need to see what OpenGL loading library you're using.

Comment: By the sounds of it you aren't doing anything yet to get the modern function pointers for your program, so youre expecting them to be picked up but only have the core old opengl functionality available. You need to load the newer profile, but really to save yourself a lot of time if this is just for getting started purposes, use something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html) to get access to functions like the ones you've mentioned for VBOs etc.

Answer (score 1):

The functions you've listed aren't loaded by default even on systems that have hardware supporting modern OpenGL. To get access to these functions you need to query the extension and load it if available.
A guide for querying and loading functions yourself can be found [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions)

If you simply want to load the extensions associated with a OpenGL version (such as 4.1/3.1 etc.) you can use something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html) to simply handle the querying and loading for you. 
If you want to use older functionality too (while not advised) then make sure to look at loading a compatibility profile to support deprecated version functionality, i.e if you are using the fixed-function pipeline flow. Not that I'd advise it!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I was able to succeed building the code by downloading GLEW.